# remove time from django DateTime in Django

Tags: python, django

So i need to remove from date Time, so i only get date, year and month.

```
"2014-04-17T00:00:00"
```

I looked at different opportunities but it didn't work

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=255)
model        = models.CharField(max_length=255)
description  = models.TextField(max_length=255)
count        = models.IntegerField(max_length= 255, default=1)
location     = models.ForeignKey('Location',  null=True, blank=True)
cover        = models.FileField(upload_to = 'static/images/', default = 'static/images/no-image.png')
created      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
barcode      = models.CharField(max_length=255)
assigned     = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
checked      = models.BooleanField(default=False)
modified     = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
tags         = TaggableManager(through=None, blank=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s' % date(self.modified, "n/j/Y")

def format_date(obj):
    return obj.modified.strftime('%d %b %Y %H:%M')
    format_date.short_description = 'Modified'
```

Comment: Not to answer your question directly, but why wouldn't you just use `DateField`? Also instead of `modified = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)` you can use `auto_now=True`, that will update the field every time it's changed. `datetime.datetime.now` is a TZ-unaware timestamp, which might cause issues later on.

Comment: `obj.modified.date().isoformat()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this works for me.

```
def get_date(self):
    return self.modified.date()
```

Comment: or can be done from a template with `{{inventory_item.modified.date}}`

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the strftime with dateutil.parser :

```
import dateutil.parser
datetime_date = dateutil.parser.parse(strf_date)
```

And then get a strftime date with the part of the datetime you need. In your case, Year, Month, Day :

```
date_only = datetime_date.strftime("%Y-%M-%d")
```

Comment: this one stays or i remove this ` modified     = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)`

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Sry

Answer (score 0):

This is code will solve your problem:

```
def get_date(dt):
    """
    Remove the time from datetime field.
    """
    return dt.strftime("%Y-%M-%d")

@property
def modified_date(self):
    return self.get_date(self.modified)
```

You can also use DateField instead of DateTimeField

[If you want in django templatetag date formatting click here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date).

Answer (score 0):

**Just replace** 
`modified = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)`
 **with** 
`modified = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.now)`

Answer (score 0):

You can store the time if required, else you can use the Date Field as mentioned [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField).

However after using DateTimeField in your models, to fetch only date via Django's ORM you can simply do the following:

To Get the Date Only:

```py
User.objects.filter('created_at__date')
```

To Get the Month Only:

```py
User.objects.filter('created_at__month')
```

To Get the Year Only:

```py
User.objects.filter('created_at__year')
```